# Parquetloader: can't load multiple parquet files using pig

Tags: apache-pig, parquet

I'm getting the following error:
Error during parsing. repetition constraint is more restrictive: can not merge type required binary MyTime into optional binary MyTime.
Maybe one of the files is corrupted but I don't know how to skip it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This happens when reading multiple parquet files that have slightly different metadata in their schemas.  Either you have a mixed collection of files in a single directory or you are giving the `LOAD` statement a glob and the resulting collection of files is mixed in this respect.

Rather than specifying the schema in an `AS()` clause or making a bare call to the loader function the solution is to override the schema in the loader function's argument like this:

```
data = LOAD 'data' 
    USING parquet.pig.ParquetLoader( 'n1:int, n2:float, n3:double, n4:long')
```

Otherwise the loader function infers the schema from the first file it encounters which then conflicts with one of the others.

If you have still have trouble try using type `bytearray` in the schema specification and then cast to the desired types in a subsequent `FOREACH`.

According to the [Parquet source code](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-pig/src/main/java/parquet/pig/ParquetLoader.java#L119) there is another argument to the loader function that allows columns to be specified by position rather than name (the default) but I have not experimented with that.

Comment: See also http://www.ericlin.me/unable-to-read-parquet-files-with-same-schema-and-different-flags-in-pig